# 2 Simultaneous Android Touches / not triggered

Tags: java, android, multi-touch

So hi there.

I have a simple Layout with 2 Views in it. Both have an onTouchListener attached.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Touching");




            return false;
        }
    });
```

But when I open the application on my phone and touch the first view and do NOT relase my finger and touch the second view with another finger, the second view wont trigger the touch event. why is this so?

Comment: You should return ``true`` from your OnTouchListeners, otherwise you won't receive more motion events than first down press.

Comment: did you read correctly? its not ONE view currently that triggers the touch events but two. So if i return true this will only have affect on the single views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case both touches are passed to the first view as a multi-touch event. So this is one event but contains (I forgot the details) both touch positions.

Comment: i think that is how i must handle it :/

Comment: you could catch the touch event in the parent view, containing both of you child-view and then for every touch event according to it's position find out which of the two child-views they are meant for.

Comment: or from the parent element i just trigger both and let them figure out. i think thats it. thanks all :)